# Why is my github repository having 17 unique cloners?

Tags: github, git-clone

I created a repository on github yesterday and did about 13 commits to it. To my surprise, there were 19 clones of this repository by 17 unique cloners. I have read the answer about git counting `git pull` as clone to, and yes I have distributed link to the repo to my friends. But at most the unique cloners should be about 6-8 at max. How come it had 17?

[image]

Comment: Where in GitHub do you find the "number of unique cloners"?

Comment: In the traffic section of the insights

Comment: It's most likely bots scanning your repos

Comment: If you have CI enabled your repo may be getting cloned for each build.